# How to use form validation to verify that document exists inside collection Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use form validation to verify that a document inside a Firestore collection does exist with flutter. When it doesn't I'm returning a String with an error message to the user. The user can only proceed after filling in a name that already exists in the database (otherwise they cannot subscribe to the right environment).
I'm using a `Form` with a `TextFormField` and a validator in my code.

Below I have included my `stateful widget` with the `Form`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:modal_progress_hud/modal_progress_hud.dart';

class BuildingScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BuildingScreenState createState() => _BuildingScreenState();
}

class _BuildingScreenState extends State<BuildingScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool showSpinner = false;
  String environment;
  bool _autoValidate = false;

  void _validateInputs() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      setState(() {
        showSpinner = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          validator: validateEnvironment,
                          onSaved: (String value) {
                            environment = value;
                          },
                        ),
                        RoundedButton(
// the RoundedButton is just a material button with some custom padding
                          buttonTitle: 'Verify',
                          onPressed: () async {
                            _validateInputs();

                            try {
                              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(
                                    context, RoosterEnvironment.id);
                              }
                              setState(() {
                                showSpinner = false;
                              });
                            } catch (e) {
                              print(e);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And below is the validateEnvironment function:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

String validateEnvironment(String value) {
  if (value != Firestore.instance.collection('environments').document(value).documentID)
    return 'Environment not on the list';
  else
    return null;
}
```

In my firestore database I have a collection called 'environments'. In this collection I have saved a document called 'test' with the field 'name: test'. Right now `(value != Firestore.instance.collection('environments').document(value).documentID)` will always be false because the firestore instance returns whatever value is plugged in the `TextFormField`. When I replace it with `(value != 'test')` the validator does work fine. I have also tried naming a collection 'test' and then validating if it exists like so: `(value != Firestore.instance.collection('test'))` but that returns an instance of 'collectionReference'.

I'm wondering if it is even possible to do this check for the form validation or should this be done in a completely different way? Any help with this would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to some help I've update my code. Now I'm using a `TextEditingController` and the code of G Griffo to check whether the value in the textfield exists in Firestore. I haven't added an error message when it doesn't exist yet, but below I included the code that works for me.

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();

static Future<bool> validateEnvironment(String docID) async {
    bool exists = false;
    try {
      await Firestore.instance
          .document("environments/$docID")
          .get()
          .then((doc) {
        if (doc.exists)
          exists = true;
        else
          exists = false;
      });
      print(exists);
      return exists;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  void _formvalidate(String docId) async {
    validateEnvironment(docId).then((value) {
      if (value == true) {
        _updateData();
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, RoosterEnvironment.id);
      } else {
      // do something
      }
    });
  }
```

And in the `onPressed` I just included the following:

```
onPressed: () {
       environment = _controller.text;
       _formvalidate(environment);
},
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you could try is by running a query to search for doc IDS to check whether the ID you have is already present in that collection.we start with a static method that does that

```
     static Future<bool> validateEnvironment(String docID) async {
    bool exists = false;
    try {
      await Firestore.instance.document("environments/$docID").get().then((doc) {
        if (doc.exists)
          exists = true;
        else
          exists = false;
      });
      return exists;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

finally from your class call the function

```
 void  _formvalidate(String docId)async{
    validateEnvironment(docId).then((value) {
      if (!value) {
       //file not found do dome stuff
....
      } else {
       //document exists do some stuff
      }
});
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to update my code a bit but your answer helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I think Firestore can query all collection data with all documents in it but Firestore can't query non-existing document names. So you can receive all the document names in a collection first, and then validate them.
Please try this

```
final snapshots = Firestore.instance.collection('environments').snapshots();

final docNameList = snapshots.map((snapshot) {
  final result = snapshot.documents
      .map((snapshot) =>  snapshot.documentID).toList();
  return result;
});
```

and you can validate like this

```
String validateEnvironment(String value) {
   if (!docNameList.data.contains(value))
     return 'Environment not on the list';
  else
     return null;
}
```

If there is a bug please let me know.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm still a flutter beginner. I tried implementing your code which I think I understand but when I try it out it's not validating, i.e. it's passing all the values as 'on the list'. I tried printing docNameList and then it gives me a value of 'Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshot, List<String>>''

Comment: Maybe I forgot that it's snapshot.
Please try !docNameList.data.contains(value)